# R Keras: Create higher rank tensor to apply reduce_mean()

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, keras

I would like to use `tf$reduce_mean()` on a list of tensors I have created and stored in a `list()`.  How can you take a list of tensors and make a higher-rank tensor that has these individual tensors as the entries in `axis=0` position of the new tensor?  I think in Python you take the list and use `np.newaxis` to make this happen (`tf$newaxis`).

I guess the larger question is: when TensorFlow in Python passes lists to its functions, like, for instance:

```py
tf.concat([a, b, c], 0)
```

What is the parallel construct in R Keras?  As you will see below, wrapping `list()` doesn't work for the way I tried it.

Here's how I can do a simple example in base R using `array()` and `apply()`:

```r
## reduce_mean() behavior I want -- mean across the matrix elements:
a <- matrix(1:4)
b <- matrix(5:8)
c <- matrix(9:12)

## How to do this in base R
(abc <- array(c(a, b, c), dim = c(2, 2, 3)))
#> , , 1
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    1    3
#> [2,]    2    4
#> 
#> , , 2
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    5    7
#> [2,]    6    8
#> 
#> , , 3
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    9   11
#> [2,]   10   12

apply(abc, MARGIN = c(1,2), FUN = mean)
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    5    7
#> [2,]    6    8
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

A guess as to something close to what it should look like in TensorFlow:

```r
library(tensorflow)

a <- tf$constant(array(1:4, dim=c(2,2)))
b <- tf$constant(array(5:8, dim=c(2,2)))
c <- tf$constant(array(9:12, dim=c(2,2)))


## Does not work
abc <- list(a, b, c)
# tf$reduce_mean(abc, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tf$stack`:

```
a <- tf$constant(array(1:4, dim=c(2,2)))
b <- tf$constant(array(5:8, dim=c(2,2)))
c <- tf$constant(array(9:12, dim=c(2,2)))

abc <- tf$stack(list(a, b, c), axis=0L)

#> tf.Tensor(
#> [[[ 1  3]
#>   [ 2  4]]
#> 
#>  [[ 5  7]
#>   [ 6  8]]
#> 
#>  [[ 9 11]
#>   [10 12]]], shape=(3, 2, 2), dtype=int32)

tf$reduce_mean(abc, axis=0L)

#> tf.Tensor(
#> [[5 7]
#>  [6 8]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=int32)
```

**Note:** don't forget putting the `L` after axis number to convert it to integer.

Comment: It is the exact answer I needed, thanks!  I would think that `tf.concat()` documentation would have a link to `tf.stack()` in tensorflows documentation.  This is outside of this question, but how would `tf$concat()` call be constructed for anything?

Comment: @mpettis I am not sure I understand your question correctly! But let me try to clarify: you need to pass a list of tensors and an axis number, e.g. `tf$concat(list(a, b, c), axis=0L)`. But, as the name suggests, it would concatenate the given tensors on the given axis, i.e. in the previous example it would become a tensor of shape `(6,2)` (versus the tensor with shape of `(3,2,2)` produced by `tf$stack`).

Comment: This and the original answer does answer this.  I was trying to figure out the correct method signature for `tf$concat()`, as I was getting an error (even though it is the wrong method to call in this case).  I wasn't interpreting the error message correctly.  I thought I was not calling the argument with the tensors correctly, but the error actually stemmed from calling the second argument with `axis=0` rather than `axis=0L`.  So this did solve it, thanks!